# confused about a matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> question:
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2 \\3&4\end{bmatrix} ,
> B=\begin{bmatrix} k&2 \\3&9\end{bmatrix},
> (AB)^5=A^5B^5$$
>   what's the value of k?

I know I can let $AB=BA$, which is 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\ k+6&20\\3k+12&42\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\ k+6&2k+8\\30&42\end{bmatrix},$$
and I can get $k=6$. But I am not pretty sure that it's the only answer.  I want to know if there is any other answer or solution to this question.

Comment: According to Mathematica, $6$ is the only solution.

Comment: We're looking for the common roots of four at-most-quintic polynomials. Suppose we can verify they're linearly independent. Since four linearly independent polynomials of the same degree must be at least cubics, we can take out at most two linear common factors, so there are at most two common roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the ground field is real or complex. We are going to show that $B$ must share a common eigenvector with $A$. Note that $B$ must be nonsingular, otherwise $k=\frac23$ but $(AB)^5\ne A^5B^5$.

By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $(AB)^5=pAB+qI$ and $B^5=rB+sI$ for some scalars $p,q,r,s$. Since $(AB)^5$ and $B^5$ are nonsingular, $(p,q),(r,s)\ne(0,0)$. The equation in question can be rewritten as $pAB+qI=A^5(rB+sI)$, or equivalently,
$$
(pA-rA^5)B = sA^5-qI.\tag{1}
$$
Since the two eigenvalues $\frac12(5\pm\sqrt{33})$ of $A$ have different magnitudes, the powers of $A$ cannot possibly be scalar matrices. It follows that both sides of $(1)$ are nonzero.

If $pA-rA^5$ is nonsingular, then $B=(pA-rA^5)^{-1}(sA^5-qI)$ commutes with $A$ and hence the two matrices share a common eigenvector.

If $pA-rA^5$ is singular, then both $pA-rA^5$ and $sA^5-qI$ are rank-one matrices. Let $pA-rA^5=xy^T$ for some nonzero vectors $x$ and $y$ and let $u,v$ be two eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the two different eigenvalues of $A$ respectively. Then $(1)$ implies that
$$
xy^TBu=au\ \text{ and }\ xy^TBv=bv\tag{2}
$$
for some scalars $a$ and $b$. As $xy^T=pA-rA^5$ is a polynomial in $A$, we also have
$$
xy^Tu=cu\ \text{ and }\ xy^Tv=dv\tag{3}
$$
for some scalars $c$ and $d$. Since $y\ne0$ and $u,v$ are linearly independent, $y^Tu$ and $y^Tv$ cannot be both zero. Assume that $y^Tu\ne0$. Then the first equation in $(3)$ implies that $c\ne0$ and $x$ is a nonzero scalar multiple of $u$. The second equation in $(3)$ thus implies that $d=0$ and $\operatorname{span}(v)=\ker(y^T)$. But then the second equation in $(2)$ implies that $b=y^TBv=0$, i.e. $Bv\in\ker(y^T)=\operatorname{span}(v)$. Hence $Bv$ is a scalar multiple of $v$.

In other words, $A$ and $B$ must share a common eigenvector. Since the two linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$ (up to scaling) are $(-3\pm\sqrt{33},\,6)^T$, we must have
$$
\pmatrix{k&2\\ 3&9}\pmatrix{x\\ 6}\propto\pmatrix{x\\ 6},
$$
for some $x\in\{-3+\sqrt{33},\ -3-\sqrt{33}\}$. Thus
$$
\frac{kx+12}{3x+54}=\frac{x}{6}.
$$
Since $x^2+6x=24$ when $x\in\{-3+\sqrt{33},\ -3-\sqrt{33}\}$, the above equation implies that
$$
k=\frac1x\left[\frac{x(3x+54)}{6}-12\right]
=\frac1x\left(\frac{x^2+18x}{2}-12\right)
=\frac1x\left(\frac{12x+24}{2}-12\right)
=6.
$$
Therefore the only possible solution is $k=6$, and it is indeed a solution because $B=A+5I$ in this case. The cases are different over other ground fields. E.g. over $GF(2)$ or $GF(3)$, every $k$ in the field is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, $A$ is invertible, and $B$ is not invertible if and only if $k=\frac23$, and in this case it is easy but slightly laborious to check $(AB)^5\neq A^5B^5$.

So $A,B$ are invertible, and we reduce to 4 quartics in $(BA)^4=A^4B^4$.  By repeated squaring and multiplying
$$
A^4B^4=
\begin{bmatrix}
199&290\\435&634
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
522 + 108 k + 18 k^2 + k^4 & 2 (837 + 93 k + 9 k^2 + k^3)\\3 (837 + 93 k + 9 k^2 + k^3)& 8055 + 108 k + 6 k^2\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
199 k^4 + 870 k^3 + 11412 k^2 + 102402 k + 832068 &
2 (199 k^3 + 2661 k^2 + 34167 k + 1334538)\\
3 (145 k^4 + 634 k^3 + 8316 k^2 + 74622 k + 606348)&6 (145 k^3 + 1939 k^2 + 24897 k + 972510)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
(BA)^4=\begin{bmatrix}
k+6 & 2k+8\\30&42
\end{bmatrix}^4
=\begin{bmatrix}
k^4 + 204 k^3 + 11736 k^2 + 201024 k + 629136 & 2 (k^4 + 184 k^3 + 9336 k^2 + 143904 k + 437760)\\
30 (k^3 + 180 k^2 + 8616 k + 109440) & 12 (5 k^3 + 800 k^2 + 33480 k + 380748)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So we want to solve
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
199 k^4 + 870 k^3 + 11412 k^2 + 102402 k + 832068 &
2 (199 k^3 + 2661 k^2 + 34167 k + 1334538)\\
3 (145 k^4 + 634 k^3 + 8316 k^2 + 74622 k + 606348)&6 (145 k^3 + 1939 k^2 + 24897 k + 972510)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
k^4 + 204 k^3 + 11736 k^2 + 201024 k + 629136 & 2 (k^4 + 184 k^3 + 9336 k^2 + 143904 k + 437760)\\
30 (k^3 + 180 k^2 + 8616 k + 109440) & 12 (5 k^3 + 800 k^2 + 33480 k + 380748)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The most promising is the right-hand column because the lower-right is just a cubic and the coefficients is more manageable, yielding:
$$
\begin{cases}
k^4 - 15 k^3 + 6675 k^2 + 109737 k - 896778 = 0\\
45 k^3 + 113 k^2 - 14021 k + 70338 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Taking out a copy of $(k-6)$, the resulting polynomials in $k$
$$
k^3 - 9 k^2 + 6621 k + 149463, 45 k^2 + 383 k - 11723
$$
are coprime.  So $k=6$ is the unique solution.